# Get root of certificate store

Tags: c#, certificate, store, x509

I need to read the root folder of a certificate store. With the following class (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=netcore-3.1) I don't see the possibility to read the root of a certificate store, I can only read the default folders of a certificate store. But we have many custom folders in our certificate stores so I need the possibility to also read them.

For example:
I created a store folder "Web Hosting" and want to read the certificates in this folder but without giving the X509Store class the Storename: "\Web Hosting".
I want to get the name of this store from the root because there are many other store folders which I don't want to hard code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything like this? https://blog.codingoutloud.com/2012/11/02/iterate-through-all-certificates-in-the-windows-certificate-store/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such term `root store` if you talk about sore hierarchy. There is no any kind of hierarchy. Certificate store is a plain list of stores where each store works for different purposes. You have to use [X509Store(String, StoreLocation, OpenFlags)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Store__ctor_System_String_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_StoreLocation_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_OpenFlags_) to query custom stores. However, you have to know store name in advance.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get all storenames of a local machine?

Comment: Not in raw .NET. You may have to use `CertEnumSystemStore` C++ function via interop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certenumsystemstore. A C++ example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-listing-system-and-physical-stores